# past simple for a duration instead of past perfect

Tags: grammar

Could you please look at these sentences and let me know which one are correct

*As the job had been vacant for a long time, he took it.*

*The job was vacant for a long time and he took it.*

*As she had been ill for a long time, she could not go to school.*

*She was ill for a long time and could not go to school.*

I know that 1 and 3 are correct but I don't know for the other ones

Comment: They all look correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

They all seem all right. However you could improve 2 and 4 as follows:

**2:**

> The job was vacant for a long time *so* he took it.

**4:**

> She was ill for a long time *so* she could not go to school.

Or

> *Since* she was ill for a long time *she* could not go to school.